# Sharing Constants Between Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch apps

Tags: cocoa, target, precompiler

I have a class that I want to share between two different applications.  The only real difference is the base framework it references.  Cocoa imports  and of course Cocoa-Touch imports .  I would like to use a precompiler directive to check what I am compiling to and allow the correct import.  What can I check to see if what My target is?  or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
#ifdef TARGET_OS_IPHONE
```